# Xamarin.Forms v3.5 application throws exception in release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an application with **Xamarin.Forms**. In Xamarin.Forms **v3.4** everything (Debugging & Publishing) is working fine.  When the Xamarin.Forms version is **upgraded to v3.5** the app throws the following error in release mode: `'Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)'`
However, it works perfectly fine in debug mode, what is the source of the problem? I've mentioned the full log file below:

```
02-13 22:34:52.932: W/monodroid(30684): Trying to load sgen from:     /data/app/com.****-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-13 22:34:58.941: A/libc(30684): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30684 (****)
02-13 22:34:59.878: W/monodroid(30740): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/com.****-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-13 22:35:06.307: A/libc(30740): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30740 (****)
02-13 22:35:06.944: W/ActivityManager(790): Process com.**** has crashed too many times: killing!
02-13 22:35:06.944: W/ActivityManager(790):   Force finishing activity 4 com.****/md5d3c8bcf50a11065f890b38bedeb79700.MainActivity
02-13 22:35:06.968: W/ActivityManager(790): Wtf, activity ActivityRecord{34f9d5f1 u0 com.****/md5d3c8bcf50a11065f890b38bedeb79700.MainActivity t457 f} in proc activity list not using proc ProcessRecord{2f9b1294 30740:com.****/u0a249}?!?
02-13 22:35:06.985: W/ActivityManager(790): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{2f9b1294 30740:com.****/u0a249}, curProc for 30740: null
02-13 22:40:16.011: W/monodroid(32271): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/com.****-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-13 22:40:22.571: A/libc(32271): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 32271 (****)
02-13 22:40:23.181: W/ActivityManager(790):   Force finishing activity 1 com.****/md5d3c8bcf50a11065f890b38bedeb79700.MainActivity
02-13 22:40:23.519: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10073 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:9105 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked:9047 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.executeAppTransition:4240 
02-13 22:40:23.520: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:803 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.updateSurfaceWindowCrop:1291 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundariesLocked:1466 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10163 
02-13 22:40:23.520: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:803 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1331 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.updateSurfaceWindowCrop:1301 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundariesLocked:1466 
02-13 22:40:23.525: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:803 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayId:808 com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.updateInputWindowsLw:311 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10414 
02-13 22:40:23.526: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.*****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.setTouchExcludeRegion:237 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setFocusedStackFrame:4083 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10490 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:9105 
02-13 22:40:23.533: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:803 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getWindowList:1399 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2863 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2764 
02-13 22:40:23.533: E/WindowState(790): getStack: Window{1f3699f8 u0 Starting com.****} couldn't find taskId=458 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:803 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2868 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2764 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2686
```

It must work without error in release mode of the Xamarin.Forms v3.5

Comment: Make sure all the other support libraries are up to date and using the correct version.  Clear your bin and obj folder and recompile.

Comment: And also note that 3.5 is quite buggie so this could be that too